# Getting value from constructor in another class

Tags: java, constructor

I am sure this is a very easy question for many, but I am struggling with it.  I am trying to get a value from the following constructor and place it in a vector.

Each time I add the object to the vector though, the value that is placed inside the vector is null.  How can I get the number to be the value that is placed into the vector?

The CInteger class:

```
public class CInteger  
{
    private int i;
    CInteger(int ii)
    {
        i = ii;
    }
}
```

And in my A1 class, the constructor and my attempt at getting the value:

```
    Object enqueue(Object o) 
    {
        CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);
        Object d = ??
        add(tailIndex, d);// add the item at the tail
    }
```

Thank you all for any insight and help, I am still learning.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

CInteger class:

```
public class CInteger implements Cloneable // Cloneable Integer 
{
    int i;
     CInteger(int ii)
    {
        this.i = ii;
    }

public int getValue()
    {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Both enqueue methods:

```
public void enqueue(CInteger i)  // enqueue() for the CInteger
{
    add(tailIndex, new Integer(i.getValue())); get int value and cast to Int object
}
public void enqueue(Date d)  // enqueue() for the Date object
{
    add(tailIndex, d);
}
```

Thank you very much everyone.  :D

Comment: What exactly are you trying to set "d" to?

Comment: I am trying to set "d" to the int value "88" from CInteger.  I can't have enqueue's parameter other than object because later on I will be enqueuing a "Date" object.

Comment: Why does enqueue have a parameter?  Are you trying to enqueue Object o, or CInteger ci?

Comment: CInteger ci.  The problem is that CInteger ci will be called from the main() as:  'CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);'  and then the next line is enqueue(ci).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overload the enqueue class to take both Dates and Integers.  In either case, it sounds like you need a method getValue() in CInteger that lets you access the int value.

```
public class CInteger
{
    //constructors, data

    public void getValue()
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

and then you can have two enqueue() methods in your other class:

```
public void enqueue(Date d)
{
    add(tailIndex, d);
}

public void enqueue(CInteger i)
{
    add(tailIndex, new Integer(i.getValue()); //access the int value and cast to Integer object
}
```

And Java will know which one you are calling automatically based on the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are actually trying to do, but I think that this will suffice:

```
Object enqueue() {
    CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);
    add(tailIndex, ci);// add the item at the tail
    return ci;  // this will automatically upcast ci as an Object
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  However, I have already tried exactly that, and I still get the value as null when printing out the vector contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class CInteger {
    private int i;

    CInteger(int ii) {
       this.i = ii;
    }
}
```

[Using the this Keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);

    encqueue(ci.i);
}

Object enqueue(Object o) 
{
    add(tailIndex, o);
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes that works, but only if the CInteger constructor is in the enqueue method.  I need the constructor in the main().

Comment: Hmm, it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish based on your question. Are you trying to construct a CInteger and then enqueue it's underlying value or something?

Comment: Okay I updated my answer to reflect that but I'm still only about 34.5% sure what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [Constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) never return any value. You have to access the value through its objects or you have to use getter methods.

In your case, "`private int i;`" can not be accessed directly. So try make either it as public or have some getter method.

So try it:

```
    CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);
    Object d = ci.i; // if i is public member
    add(tailIndex, d);
```

or

```
    ...
    private int i;
    ...
    public int getI() {
        return  this.i;
    }
    ...
    CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);
    Object d = ci.getI(); 
    add(tailIndex, d);
```